# WPF: How to walk up the Visual Tree to find a Model3DGroup a clicked 3d-model is in?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-tree

I'm displaying a few 3D-models as Model3DGroups.
They are surrounded by Viewport3D which catches MouseDown-events.

I want to determine which Model3DGroup (they all have names) was clicked.
I'm starting with this:

```
        Point location = e.GetPosition(karte.ZAM3DViewport3D);
        HitTestResult hitResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(karte.ZAM3DViewport3D, location);

        if (hitResult != null )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("BREAKPOINT");
            // Hit the visual.
        }
```

After hitting the breakpoint set at the WriteLine-command I'm looking at the local-view to find the right variable but can't find it.
Can you help me out which path I need to take to find the group, the modelvisual3d belongs to?

Here is a screenshot of the tree:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by surrounding the Model3DGroup with a ModelUIElement3D.

```
<ModelUIElement3D MouseDown="ModelUIElement3D_MouseDown" x:Name="LogoMouseDown">
```

the MouseDown-function handles it this way:

```
    private void ModelUIElement3D_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

            if (sender == trololo)
            {
                RaiseModelClickEvent("auditorium");    
            }
            else if (sender == LogoMouseDown)
            {
                RaiseModelClickEvent("logo");
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Linq to Visual Tree](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/03/04/linq-to-visual-tree.html) as it doesn't matter whether the named element you are looking for is Model3DGroup. It is just another Dependency Object (if I understand your question).

Check result's type and then LinqToVT to go up, retrieving it's XAML predecessor:

```
hitResult.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(ModelVisual3D)
```

Comment: I avoided LINQ until today, but I guess its time to work with it.

I could use a workaround for my problem by encapsulating a Model3DGroup within a ModelUIElement3D which also can trigger Mouse-Events.